# Заблокировать закрытие модального окна по нажатию на сабмит bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отменить стандартное бутстраповское закрытие модального окна по клику на сабмит. Делаю это с целью добавить проверку в форме попапа. Можно ли как-то заблокировать это действие до тех пор пока форма не будет отвалидирована?

Comment: Вы форму будете AJAX-ом валидировать?

Comment: я буду ajax после валидации выполнять, т.е валидация  js прошла - отправляю аякс, и потом еще в пыхе провалидирую...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это довольно просто и относится не именно к bootstrap.

**Нативный JavaScript:**

```js
$('#myModal').modal({
  show: false
});

function play() {
  alert('Ваша функция!');
}

document.querySelector('#myform').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  play(); // Ваша функция
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form id="myform" action="#" method="#" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <input type="text" name="contact-name" placeholder="Name*">
            <input type="tel" name="contact-phone" placeholder="Phone*">
            <input type="text" name="contact-message" placeholder="Message">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Вешаем обработчик события «submit» на нашу форму, а далее используем **event.preventDefault();** для отмены события по умолчанию.

> **event.preventDefault();** Отменяет событие, если оно отменяемое, без остановки дальнейшего распространения этого события.
>   [Подробнее на developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Отменяем событие и дальше запускаем, что нам нужно; в данном случае функцию **play**.

**jQuery:**

```js
$('#myModal').modal({
  show: false
});

function play() {
  alert('Ваша функция!');
}


$("#myform").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  play();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form id="myform" action="#" method="#" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <input type="text" name="contact-name" placeholder="Name*">
            <input type="tel" name="contact-phone" placeholder="Phone*">
            <input type="text" name="contact-message" placeholder="Message">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: я решил чуток иначе, переопределил id модалки и дописал своего кода руцями... спасибо за еще один вариант)

Comment: Рад был помочь, если мой ответ устраивает, пожалуйста, примите его(поставьте галку где плюсовалка).